# Conditionally set IAM policy based on whether a certain resource exists or not in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-kms

I'm trying to set the KMS key policy based on whether an IAM role exists or not. The yaml file looks like this.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "key_policy" {
  statement {
    sid = "Give Access to the my Role"

    actions = [
      "kms:GenerateDateKey",
      "kms:Decrypt"
    ]

    resources = ["*"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${var.account_id}:role/myrole"]
    }
  }
}
```

The issue with this terraform script is that it would fail if `myrole` doesn't exist in my account. We have multiple AWS accounts and only part of them has this `myrole`. Our CI will run this same script for all the accounts. Is there a way to apply this statement only if `myrole` exists?

Comment: Is the `myrole` managed by terraform, or is its existence totally independent of terraform configuration you use in each account?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Marcin. It is managed by a different set of terraform scripts. Those scripts are running separately under a different CI. That being said, I'm not sure if it is possible to share the existence state between these two sets of scripts.

Answer (score 6):

The design principles of terraform (TF) dictate the a current TF configuration file should **explicitly define** your infrastructure. This means that resources that define your solution are only managed by a given configuration files and current TF state. If some resource is not in TF state, it simply is considered outside of the scope of TF and as non-existent.

As a consequence, TF **does not directly support** checking for existence of any resources nor [conditional creation of resources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/composition.html#conditional-creation-of-objects) based on such conditions. This would lead to issues as your TF would not fully represent your architectures.

Therefor, [TF docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/composition.html#conditional-creation-of-objects) recommend:

> Rather than trying to write a module that itself tries to detect whether something exists and create it if not, we recommend applying the **dependency inversion approach**: making the module accept the object it needs as an argument, via an **input variable**.

Based on the above, you should aim to develop your `aws_iam_policy_document.key_policy` so that it creates the `statement` in question based on an **input variable**. This means that your CICD pipeline would have to check for the existence of the role and pass this information to your CF file as an input variable, e.g. `my_role_exists` with `true` and `false` values.

Then, you could use [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) to make the `statement` conditional:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "key_policy" {

  dynamic "statement" {

    for_each = var.my_role_exists == true ? [1] : [] 

    content {
      sid = "Give Access to the my Role"

      actions = [
        "kms:GenerateDateKey",
        "kms:Decrypt"
      ]

      resources = ["*"]

      principals {
        type        = "AWS"
        identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${var.account_id}:role/myrole"]
      }
    }
   } 
}
```